# Fetching Data from Database and display in View by using MVC entity frame work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating one application by using MVC entity framework. In my application user will login with email ID and will enter the task details and later user can able to view the data which saved. Unfortunately not able to display the data for particular user as all the users data coming into the view.
    Below is the code for the Controller

```
public ActionResult TaskDetails(string td)
{
    using (Data DE = new Data())
    {
        var email = Session["Email"].ToString();
        var displaydata = DE.TaskDetails.Where(u => u.ProjectID.ToString() == email).ToList();
        ViewBag.details = displaydata;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Here email id is from one table and projectID from one table and by using primary key I am trying to get the data. But unfortunately all the users data is  coming.

This is code for my View

```
@model MVC_Sample.Models.TaskDetail
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TaskDetails</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TaskDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div> 
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.details)
            {
                <table id="t01">
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.ProjectID</td>
                        <td>@item.ProjectName</td>
                        <td>@item.StartDate</td>
                        <td>@item.EstimatedDate</td>
                        <td>@item.TaskDescription</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Can any one help me to find where I did mistake.

Comment: I think your email variable doesn't have any value, have you debugged the code?

Comment: Yes I did. there is email value coming into tht variable.

Comment: Why you are checking `ProjectID==Email`? Does your projectID is an email?

Comment: ProjectID and Email both are in different..by using project id I am trying to get the details

Comment: Actually I need to display the Project details of User who currently logged in.

Comment: Have you linked your Project Table with Users' table, if you already done this, then you can get the projects related to a specfic user if not then how can you decide which project belongs to who?

Comment: Done.. Its working now